# Adding multiple TextViews into LinearLayout programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, textview

There is long string. I am dividing long string into words and setting TextView for each word. 
(You can ask why I need this function? When user clicks on textview(word), application shows the meaning of the word)

```
...
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setTextSize(24);
                tv.setText(word);
                ll.addView(tv);
...
```

My LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llReader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
```

If I put LinearLayout's orientation vertical, it is putting each TextView in new line.
For example:

> word1
>
> word2
>
> word3

If I put it in horizontal orientation, it is putting all words only in one line:

> word 1, word 2, word 3

In result word4,word5, word6 is not visible.

How to add TextViews programmatically in this way?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You should add **Horizontal LinearLayout** in your **Vertical LinearLayout**:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/verticalLinear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/horizontalLinear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your activity,

```
private LinearLayout mReaderLayout;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mReaderLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.llReader);
}

private void addText(String text) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setText(text);
    mReaderLayout.addView(textView);
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. But I asked how to add textviews into linearlayout in the way shown in picture: paragraph of TextViews

Answer (score 0):

You can use gridview with adapter.

```
  <GridView
                    android:id="@+id/gridview1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:columnWidth="50dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >

                </GridView>
```

and in `onCreate`:

```
    String[] strings= "Long string".split(" ");
       gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview1);  

              // Create adapter to set value for grid view
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strings);

                gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

                gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                        int position, long id) {

                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        ((TextView) v).getText()  , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add use a RelativeLayout right away or you can add a two buttons in a linear, vertical Layout and then add that into a horizontal layout. Then add the next vertical linear layout with the other two buttons into the horizontal layout.